# Simulate slow network connection for Chrome extensions using React-NextJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, google-developer-tools

I am developing a Chrome extension that requires me to throttle download bandwidth on the browser programmatically (client-side). After going through almost everything I could find on the web on [Google extension](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/), I couldn't find any way of doing that.
Has anyone succeeded in simulating a slow network on the google chrome browser? Or is there an alternative?

Note I am aware that this can be done on the network tab. But my aim is to do it programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to simulate a throttled network you are far better off doing so "below" the application layer because if you slow things down up at the application layer you will induce behaviours in things like TCP which would not be present in the "real" throttled network.

So, if you are on Linux, you should look into the "netem" queuing discipline.  it will operate below TCP and so TCP will see something which looks more like an actual, throttled network.  There should be similar tools for other OSes.

Comment: My desire is to do this using Google extension itself. I actually don't butter that much about the TCP and other transport protocols. I am interested in just throttling the network.